# What books should every software tester read?

Tags: training

Why those? What is it that makes you recommend those books above others?

Answer (score 1):

**Below mentioned these are the books name with authors for learning Software testing.**

https://dzone.com/articles/12-impressive-books-every-tester-should-read

- Foundation of Software Testing by **Cem Kaner**
- Selenium Testing Tools Cookbook by **Unmesh Gundecha**
- Software Testing by **Ron Patton**
- Agile Estimating and Planning by **Mike Cohn**
- A Practical Guide to Testing in DevOps by **Katrine Clokie**
- Bug Advocacy by **Cem Kaner** and **Rebecca Fiedler**
- The Agile Samurai by **Jonathan Rasmusson**
- Implementing Automated Software Testing: How to Save Time and Lower Costs While Raising Quality by **Elfriede Dustin, Thom Garrett, Bernie Gauf**
- Lessons Learned in Software Testing by Cem Kaner
- Experience of Test Automation by **Dorothy Graham & Mark Fewster**
- A Practitioner’s Guide to Software Test Design by Lee Copeland
- How to Break Software: A Practical Guide to Testing by **James Whittaker**